# Create Table from List

Tags: c#

I have a list that I want to use to create a table that's evenly spread out across columns.
So I would take:

```
function_id
exception rpt  
alarm maint    
ratio adder    
temp ratio     
change         
access         
aet sequence   
eng display    
line set       
clear repeaters
enable function
volt setpoint  
feed setpoint  
feed report    
volt report    
problem pot    
temp voltage   
flag pc in/out 
tap enable
```

And create the following (Sorry about the format):

```
Col1--------------Col2--------------Col3--------------Col4--------------Col5--------------Col6

exception rpt   eng display     volt report     ae map          search/starve   amps volts     
alarm maint     line set        problem pot     exception log   votrax watch    search screen  
ratio adder     clear repeaters temp voltage    pot status      bath, metal     newpot         
temp ratio      enable function flag pc in/out  noise report    alarm watch     pcram v/o      
change          volt setpoint   tap enable      select pots     repeater check  
access          feed setpoint   set enable      shift summary   pcram           
aet sequence    feed report     enable status   trace report    ratio entry
```

What I have now works but seems like there should be a more efficient way:

```
    public DataTable CreateMenuTable()
    {

        DataTable userFunctions = GetMenus();
        DataTable menuTable = new DataTable();
        DataRow menuRow;
        int rowNum = 0;

        int numColumns = (int)Math.Sqrt(userFunctions.Rows.Count);
        int numRows = (int)Math.Ceiling(userFunctions.Rows.Count / (float)numColumns);

        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++)
        {
            menuTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col" + (i + 1), System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        {
            menuRow = menuTable.NewRow();
            menuTable.Rows.Add(menuRow);
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in userFunctions.AsEnumerable())
        {
            if (rowNum < numRows)
            {
                menuRow = menuTable.Rows[rowNum];
                menuRow["Col1"] = row["function_id"];                 
            }

            if (rowNum >= numRows & rowNum < (numRows * 2))
            {
                menuRow = menuTable.Rows[rowNum - (numRows)];
                menuRow["Col2"] = row["function_id"];
            }

            if (rowNum >= (numRows * 2) & rowNum < (numRows * 3))
            {
                menuRow = menuTable.Rows[rowNum - (numRows * 2)];
                menuRow["Col3"] = row["function_id"];
            }

            if (rowNum >= (numRows * 3) & rowNum < (numRows * 4))
            {
                menuRow = menuTable.Rows[rowNum - (numRows * 3)];
                menuRow["Col4"] = row["function_id"];
            }

            if (rowNum >= (numRows * 4) & rowNum < (numRows * 5))
            {
                menuRow = menuTable.Rows[rowNum - (numRows * 4)];
                menuRow["Col5"] = row["function_id"];
            }

            if (rowNum >= (numRows * 5) & rowNum < (numRows * 6))
            {
                menuRow = menuTable.Rows[rowNum - (numRows * 5)];
                menuRow["Col6"] = row["function_id"];
            }

            rowNum++;                
        }
        return menuTable;
    }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Looks like c#

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to display this on three columns or put this in a database? If it is the later, that is a crazy idea. If it is the former, you shouldn't need to mess with DataTable.

Comment: Sorry, yes it's c#, meant to put that in the title.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with a specific presentation layer: it's just trying to take a list of strings and group them into columns to produce a squarish `DataTable`.

Comment: @Aron my goal is to use it to display a menu base on the values in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid all the `if` thing like this:

```
// Calculate to which column this should belong
int columnNumber = rowNum / numRows + 1;
// % just return the remainder of the division between two numbers
// if you think about it it's the same as rowNum - (numRows)*K
menuRow = menuTable.Rows[rowNum % numRows];
// put it in the right column
menuRow["Col"+columnNumber] = row["function_id"];
```